# SQL SELECT in PHP while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I a set of tables and fields that I would like to select data from. I have tried the below code without success. Could any one explain to me why this does not work, and if possible, how to make it work.

```
$fields = "table1.field1, table2.field2, table3.field3, table4.field4";
$tables = "table1, table2, table3, table4";
$table = explode(', ', $tables); //explode the tables string
$field = explode(', ', $fields); //explode the fields string


$i=1;
while ($i<=4) { 
$sql = 'SELECT ' . $field[$i] . ' FROM ' . $table[$i] . ' WHERE ' . $field[$i] . ' LIKE "%' . $str . '%";';
$results = $readConn->query($sql);
$i++;
var_dump($results);
}
```

Comment: You the whole set of tables and fields?

Comment: It's rather hard to say why something doesn't work without you telling us exactly [what it's supposed to do](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code) and what it actually does. For DB queries & results, example source and result data helps tremendously. What's the relation (if any) between the data in the four tables? You can probably fetch the results in a single query using [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL you're creating looks like this:

```
SELECT table2.field2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.field2 LIKE "%%";
SELECT table3.field3 FROM table3 WHERE table3.field3 LIKE "%%";
SELECT table4.field4 FROM table4 WHERE table4.field4 LIKE "%%";
SELECT  FROM  WHERE  LIKE "%%";
```

I don't know what you're setting $str to, so I don't have it included here.
The SQL should run, it looks fine, except that last one ... You'll want to adjust your loop to be, <4, instead of <=4

Are you sure that you have a valid connection to the database? Are you getting back NULL or something as a result, or an error?

Also, item #2 in Mark's answer.
Also, personally, I find this a lot more readable.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s LIKE '%%s%'", $field[$i], $table[$i], $field[$i], $str);
```

than this

```
$sql = 'SELECT ' . $field[$i] . ' FROM ' . $table[$i] . ' WHERE ' . $field[$i] . ' LIKE "%' . $str . '%";';
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things I can see:

1) You forgot the `SELECT` keyword:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ' .  $field[$i] . ' FROM ' ...etc...
```

2) In SQL strings should be escaped with single quotes, not double quotes. The result should resemble `LIKE '%foo%'` instead of `LIKE "%foo%"`.

Comment: Yeah, that'd help ... = ]. Also, I think when doing inline SQL like this, you can attempt to make it more legible by using $sql = sprinft("...");

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I do have the SELECT in there. I just forgot to add it in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the SELECT keyword in the queries you generate.  If you print out $sql it'll be obvious what the problem is.  Incidentally, depending on where $str is coming from, you might be leaving yourself vulnerable to a SQL injection attack unless you escape it correctly.